# Run and debug program from VSCode as root

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ssh

I connect to the device via Remote - SSH. And I need to run and debug the program as a superuser. How can I do this?

Right now I'm using

```
>sudo su
```

in the TERMINAL. But that's a temporary solution. (I'm working C/C++ language if that makes a difference.)

Comment: Establish the ssh connection as root?

Comment: Yes, you can do something like `ssh root@remote` to connect to the root account on the remote.

Comment: ssh connection without sudo. Just name@1.1.1.1, but name is superuser. When I launch App with terminal I must call sudo /bin/App